# How can I read this file in MATLAB?

Tags: file, matlab, matlab-load

I have a file named `data.dat` with the following contents:

> my name is elyas 123
>
> this is a book 123.450
>
> my father name -2.34e+05

I want load this file into MATLAB and get the following data as output:

```
a = 123
b = 123.450
c = -2.34e+05
name = 'elyas'
```

But I don't know how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to give the format rules.  So, is name always going to be the first token after "my name is"?  Will a always be the final token after that?

What about b, it is the last token on third line, first token after the first token that starts with letter b?  What about c, is it the final token?

To parse this file, we need to know the rules of the file format.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it using [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) to read each of the 3 lines:

```
fid = fopen('data.dat','rt');                 %# Open the file
data = textscan(fid,'%*s %*s %*s %s %f',1);   %# Read the first line, ignoring
                                              %#   the first 3 strings
name = data{1}{1};                            %# Get the string 'name'
a = data{2};                                  %# Get the value for 'a'
data = textscan(fid,'%*s %*s %*s %*s %f',1);  %# Read the second line, ignoring
                                              %#   the first 4 strings
b = data{1};                                  %# Get the value for 'b'
data = textscan(fid,'%*s %*s %*s %f',1);      %# Read the third line, ignoring
                                              %#   the first 3 strings
c = data{1};                                  %# Get the value for 'c'
fclose(fid);                                  %# Close the file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html).